# MariaDB: ALTER TABLE command works on one table, but not the other

Tags: django, django-models, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have two tables (Django Models) in a MariaDB database: `coredb_vsatservicerate` and `coredb_simservicerate`.

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `coredb_simservicerate`;
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| coredb_simservicerate | CREATE TABLE `coredb_simservicerate` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`service_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`old` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`year` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL CHECK (`year` >= 0),
`reseller` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`description_update_ts` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

And

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate`;
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| coredb_vsatservicerate | CREATE TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`cir_download` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cir_upload` int(11) NOT NULL,
`mir_download` int(11) NOT NULL,
`mir_upload` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`sector` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`coverage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`old` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`year` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL CHECK (`year` >= 0),
`reseller` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`bandwidth_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` longtext NOT NULL,
`description_update_ts` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `coredb_vsatservicera_coverage_id_737c0f97_fk_coredb_co` (`coverage_id`),
KEY `coredb_vsatservicera_bandwidth_id_b8943d2d_fk_coredb_da` (`bandwidth_id`),
CONSTRAINT `coredb_vsatservicera_bandwidth_id_b8943d2d_fk_coredb_da` FOREIGN KEY (`bandwidth_id`) REFERENCES `coredb_dataratecombo` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `coredb_vsatservicera_coverage_id_737c0f97_fk_coredb_co` FOREIGN KEY (`coverage_id`) REFERENCES `coredb_coverage` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.014 sec)
```

For `coredb_simservicerate` this command works fine:

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> ALTER TABLE `coredb_simservicerate` MODIFY `price` numeric(9, 2) NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

For `coredb_vsatservicerate` this similar command throws an error:

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> ALTER TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate` MODIFY `price` decimal(9, 2) NULL;       
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '`servicedbtest`.`U0`.`year`' in 'CHECK'
```

I have looked at MariaDB's documentation and still no idea why.

Can you help me?
Is this a Bug in MariaDB?

**EDIT:**

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> show variables like "%version%"
 -> ;
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                     | Value                                    |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| in_predicate_conversion_threshold | 1000                                     |
| innodb_version                    | 10.3.29                                  |
| protocol_version                  | 10                                       |
| slave_type_conversions            |                                          |
| system_versioning_alter_history   | ERROR                                    |
| system_versioning_asof            | DEFAULT                                  |
| version                           | 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1                |
| version_comment                   | Debian 10                                |
| version_compile_machine           | x86_64                                   |
| version_compile_os                | debian-linux-gnu                         |
| version_malloc_library            | system                                   |
| version_source_revision           | 4f143a88bcb36e94e9edba8a3c5b4a350dcd9bf9 |
| version_ssl_library               | YaSSL 2.4.4                              |
| wsrep_patch_version               | wsrep_25.24                              |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

**EDIT 2**: replaced the DESCRIBE output with SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

**EDIT 3:** If I remove the check constraint from `year`, the aforementioned `ALTER TABLE` seems to work.

```
MariaDB [servicedbtest]> ALTER TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate` MODIFY `year` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [servicedbtest]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate`;
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| coredb_vsatservicerate | CREATE TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `cir_download` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cir_upload` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mir_download` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mir_upload` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sector` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coverage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `reseller` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bandwidth_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description_update_ts` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `coredb_vsatservicera_coverage_id_737c0f97_fk_coredb_co` (`coverage_id`),
  KEY `coredb_vsatservicera_bandwidth_id_b8943d2d_fk_coredb_da` (`bandwidth_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `coredb_vsatservicera_bandwidth_id_b8943d2d_fk_coredb_da` FOREIGN KEY (`bandwidth_id`) REFERENCES `coredb_dataratecombo` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `coredb_vsatservicera_coverage_id_737c0f97_fk_coredb_co` FOREIGN KEY (`coverage_id`) REFERENCES `coredb_coverage` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1424 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [servicedbtest]> ALTER TABLE `coredb_vsatservicerate` MODIFY `old` decimal(9, 2) NULL;
Query OK, 374 rows affected (0.090 sec)            
Records: 374  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Is this a Bug in MariaDB 10.3 ?

Comment: Replace DESCRIBE outputs with SHOW CREATE TABLE ones.

Comment: I have replaced the output as requested.

Comment: I tested on MySQL 8.0 and got no error. So I assume this has something to do with the different implementation of CHECK constraints in MariaDB. Therefore I removed the [tag:mysql] tag. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and gradually it has been diverging from MySQL since then. You should now consider MariaDB to be a different software product, not compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this using a MariaDB 10.5 docker-container ( https://hub.docker.com/r/mariadb/columnstore ) and the issue didn't occur there.

It seems that this is a Bug in the version that is currently in the Debian-Stable APT-repositories.

## Upgrading to 10.5 fixes the issue.

Thanks to Akina and Bill Karwin for help