# MySQL Unknown column in CHECK

Tags: mysql, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have a MySQL database And I want to add a column:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use myDatabase;
Database changed
MariaDB [myDatabase]>

ALTER TABLE material add new_column FLOAT;
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '`myDatabase`.`m`.`existing_column`' in 'CHECK'
```

Sure enough, the `existing_column` is in the table `material`:

```
MariaDB [myDatabase]> describe material;                                                         
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+       
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |       
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+       
| id                           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |       
| existing_column              | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |       
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+       
42 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

(i've left out the other columns for clarity)

And there is a CHECK constraint in place:

```
MariaDB [myDatabase]> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = "material";
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | CHECK_CLAUSE                        |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
| def                | myDatabase        | material   | CONSTRAINT_1    | `existing_column` in (0,1)          |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.007 sec)
```

I've tried:

- Making sure all values in `existing_column` are either 0 or 1 -> No change
- Dropping the CHECK -> I just get the same error when I try:

```
MariaDB [myDatabase]> alter table material drop constraint CONSTRAINT_1;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '`myDatabase`.`m`.`existing_column`' in 'CHECK'
```

- making an sqldump and importing it on another system -> No error and I can add my column!

Context:

- I'm using mysql 10.3.29 on Debian 10
- I normally use [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) and [flask-migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for managing migrations. That's where I got the error initially.
- I don't really need the CHECK constraint. Sqlalchemy added it automatically

Comment: In stead of `describe material;`, you should do `SHOW CREATE TABLE material;` because this also show existing constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Linking this issue here because it's similar: [MariaDB: ALTER TABLE command works on one table, but not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083269/mariadb-alter-table-command-works-on-one-table-but-not-the-other/68098357#68098357)

I was running MariaDB on Debian: `10.5.10-MariaDB-1:10.5.10+maria~buster`

I could apply schema to other databases, but I was getting stuck on one table that kept raising the same error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '`database`.`table`.`col`' in 'CHECK'
```

Updating MariaDB to `10.5.15` allowed me to apply the schema. It might have just needed a restart - but impossible to know now.

Comment: In my case just restart was enough!